# How to resolve plot with 20000 points?

Tags: plot, astropy, spectrum, spectra

I 'm trying to plot a spectrum of a Star given some data. The data set spans about 21,000 points.

```
import numpy as np
import astropy.units as u
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from specutils import Spectrum1D
data = ascii.read("SSD1.csv", data_start=1)

wavelength = data['col1']*u.AA
flux = data['col2']*u.Jy
spec1d = Spectrum1D(spectral_axis=wavelength, flux=flux)
ax = plt.subplots()[1]  
ax.plot(spec1d.spectral_axis, spec1d.flux)  
ax.set_xlabel("Dispersion")  
ax.set_ylabel("Flux")
```

This is the plot i get:
[Plot of Flux vs Wavelength](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qY5he.png)

It's too difficult to resolve the spectra, how can i make it smooth like this?

[Smoother plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wKAN.png)

Comment: Since you are using specutils, have you tried any of its built-in facilities for [smoothing and resampling](https://specutils.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manipulation.html#smoothing)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Iguananaut ! That helped clear up some things.

Comment: If you found a solution feel free to post it as your own answer; if not maybe you can update your question with here you ran into trouble.